# Call Singleton EJB during initializing a static variable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, static, ejb

I have a thread safe heavy resource and I would like to initialize this as a static class variable. During initializing this object I need to read some "connection" parameters from external property file.

To read the init parameters I would like to use my exicting `Configuration` Singleton EJB  but it seems that my injected `configuration` bean is null at deployment time (when EE container initializes my static variable).

**This is my Configuration EJB:**

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class Configuration {

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public String getValue(String key) {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

**This is the way how I would like to initialize my HeavyObject:**

```
@Stateless
public class SenderBean {

    private static HeavyObject something;

    @Inject
    private Configuration configuration;

    public SendNotificationBean()  {
        String host = configuration.getValue("....");
        String port= configuration.getValue("....");

        something = new HeavyObject(host, port);
    }
}
```

But `configuration` is null:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.aaa.bbb.business.SenderBean.configureProxy(SenderBean.java:187)
```

Maybe I need to change the order how container initializes EJB-s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work since the container calls the default constructor before it injects anything. There is an annotation `@PostConstruct` for that.

To get around this I would also make `HeavyObject` a singleton bean and inject `Configuration` in it. Something like:

```
@Singleton
public class HeavyObject {

    @Inject
    private Configuration conf;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configure() {
        // make something with the conf
    }

}
```

and inject it:

```
@Stateless
public class SenderBean {

    @Inject
    private HeavyObject ho;
    ...
}
```

Of course this is just only one way to do it but I would recommend to avoid static stuff in beans and think carefully what is in the beans responsibility. 
That is why I have put the `@PostConstruct` configuration logic to `HeavyObject` singleton instead of running it on the `SenderBean`.

Nothing still hinders you to inject `Configuration` to `SenderBean` also if there is use for that.